# Symbolic logic proof

Tags: logic, quantifiers

Can any one please give me the correct proof for this, i got this far but i am stuck.

Thank you!

Comment: I cannot tell what you are asking. Could you please remove the screen shot and explain your question in natural language? Explain what you are trying to prove and the exact deductive system you are allowed to use.

Comment: @user148006 What is happening at line 9? Is this a premise?

Comment: yes that is a premise of the sub proof

Comment: @user148006 I guess that's another way to do it. I'm not sure how your system works, but shouldn't line 12 then refer to two lines that contradict one another like line 11 does?

Comment: Yes exactly, it should contradict but i am not sure which one.

Comment: @user148006 After line 11, there should probably be $\neg \exists z: \neg R(a,z)$ (~ Intro) which contradicts line 8.

Comment: I managed to finish the proof. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: @user148006 - Which is the question? What are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In (3) you have correctly "instantiated" (1) with $a$ new.

Then you have correctly assumed $Fa$ in order to derive by $\rightarrow$-elim : $\exists z \lnot R(a,z)$.

Now you "instantiate" it , preliminary to $\exists$-elimination, with $b$ new, to get : $\lnot R(a,b)$.

But from (3), by $\land$-elim, you have also $\forall z R(a,z)$.

Thus, you can use $b$ to get : $R(a,b)$.

**Now** you have your contradiction, with $R(a,b)$ and $\lnot R(a,b)$, i.e $\bot$.

But you have derived $\bot$ "under the assumption" 9 for $\exists$-Elimination.

Applying this rule [see *Comment*] in your example, we have that $\bot$ is your $\theta$, and you can conclude it "discharging" the assumption $¬R(a,b)$ in 9 [which is the $\sigma(b)$ of the rule], because you have $∃z¬R(a,z)$ in 8 [i.e. the $\exists z \sigma(z)$ of the rule].

Now, having derived $\bot$, you can use $\lnot$-intro to discharge the assumption $Fa$ and derive $\lnot Fa$ (this is your new step 13).

With (4) : $Ga$

and (13) : $\lnot Fa$

you can use $\land$-intro to derive :

(14)  $Ga \land \lnot Fa$

and then conclude with $\exists$-intro :

(15) $\exists y (G(y) \land \lnot F(y))$.

*Comment*

This is the formal statement of $∃$-Elimination, form Richard Kaye, *The Mathematics of Logic* (2007), page 122 :

> (∃-Elimination) To show $Σ \cup \{ ∃zσ(z) \} \vdash θ$ it suffices to show $Σ \cup \{ σ(b) \} \vdash θ$, provided the substitution is valid and the variable $b$ is a new variable not already free in some formula in $Σ$ nor in $θ$.

An instance of $∃$-Elimination looks like the following :

*(1)* $∃z \sigma(z)$

*(2)* Let $b$ satisfy $\sigma(b)$

...

*(3)* $\theta$

*(4)* $\theta$ --- by $∃$-Elimination.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. I finished most of the steps, stuck in two of them, could you please check the new image i posted with the updated steps.

Comment: @user148006 - the new step 9 is wrong; follow my hints, please: from 3 by $\land$-elim you have derived $Ga$ in step 4, but you have also $\forall z R(a,z)$. You have to use this one with $b$ introduced in step 8 to get $R(a,b)$ in 9, and this is the requested contradiction which license you to conclude $\lnot Fa$.

Comment: I am unable to figure out what i did wrong, if its not too much to ask could you please give me the steps with the subproofs.

Comment: @user148006 - now is Ok.

Comment: I still dont understand where i went wrong, if you can correct my proof that would be great!

Comment: Step 12 should be something else other than what i have, and i am unable to figure out what that is supposed to be.

Comment: But the proof still doesn't check out, what do i write for Step 12?

Comment: @user148006 - but are you using a software ? If so, it is not clear to me what is your problem ? If I work "by hand" there is a rule called $\exists$-elim; you are applying it going from 8 to 9. With it you assume a new term ($b$) and you conclude with $\bot$. Then the rule says : if $\phi(t) \vdash \sigma$ then $\exists x \phi(x) \vdash \sigma$, **provided that** $t$ is not  contained into $\sigma$. $\bot$ is the $\sigma$, and you conclude it "discharging" the assumption $\lnot R(a,b)$, because you have $\exists z \lnot R(a,z)$. 1/2

Comment: You have to check your textbook for a more complete explanation of the rule... 2/2

Comment: The program i use is called Fitch. I understand the part till step 9. But my final conclusion still does not check out.

Comment: @user148006 - because steps 9-11 is called $\exists$-elim; assuming that your software is right **but** is not able to explain to you the rules, you have to read how the rule works on a textbook (see for example [Natural Deduction](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~plragde/cs245/06-prednd.pdf) page 16-17).

Comment: 9 - 11 are correct but there should be a step before ~P(a) thats where i am getting it wrong.

Comment: I appreciate your help but do i delete step 12 or do i write something else there because it is a subproof.

Comment: Hey, step 12 should highlight which steps? And also step 16 should conclude based on what steps? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Hey! Thank you very much i figured it out. You very helpful :D

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort, this question has been solved :)